# Electron can not auto update in mac with version big sur

Tags: electron, electron-builder, macos-big-sur

I upgraded electron to 9.4.0 and electron-buiilder to 22.9.1 in Mac Big Sur.

I used the autoUpdater and dialog from electron to show successful or failed message.

However, it kept saying ***code signature at URL  did not pass validation***.

When I built the OS version, the ***signing*** phase is passed. Also, I tried to `codesign -dvvvv --extract-certificates` to see the hash information and is the same with the workable one.

I am wondering if the new version of mac caused this issue?

```
 const {autoUpdater, dialog} = require("electron");
 dialog.showMessageBox(dialogOpts);
```